# How to use data fetching method on _app.js component nextjs

Tags: reactjs, next.js

**Is there any way to use the nextjs data fetching method in my custom App component (_app.js) to fetch data in the server side**, or if there are no methods is it necessary to fetch data only in the server side?

Comment: Please someone help me!

Comment: Are you trying to fetch data client-side? There are several libraries that provide hooks for data fetching, or you could just call [`fetch()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API) inside of a `useEffect` hook or callback.

Comment: Thank you for your help Calvin, but I know how to fetch data on the client side, my question is can I fetch data in the server side in _app.js comopnent

Comment: If you want fetch data server-side, I think you'd have to do server-side rendering. This documentation might be helpful (specifically, `getInitialProps` and the caveats of using it in _app.js): https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/custom-app

Comment: Yes the documentation was very useful, thank you so much! 

Comment: Subash R K and Calvin can you help me in solving out my issue similar to yours here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72220011/is-there-any-method-to-overcome-the-error-of-hydration-ui-in-next-js-while-using